# Is FindShortestTour really exact?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I have read online that the FindShortestTour function on Mathematica uses the Concorde TSP solver, which is meant to provide exact solutions. However, I have been playing with this problem on my own, and it solved a randomly generated layout of 500,000 cities in just a few minutes (screenshot attached). Isn't this greater than the maximum TSP problem that has ever been solved exactly (80,000 cities)? So is FindShortestTour an approximate algorithm, and if so how much can I expect the results to deviate from the true shortest tour.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please read the documentation for [`FindShortestTour`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html), especially the section _Possible issues_. Note that there are [several methods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23736/75628) that can be invoked by `FindShortestTour`.

Comment: I've read through the documentation, thank you! What I'm curious about is if the method is always guaranteed to be exact - and if not, is it known how much it usually deviates from the true optimal path?

Comment: But the answer to your question is very clearly written [_in the documentation_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html#269190607).

Comment: I think this is a fair question, and I don't think that the documentation is very clear. This should be clearly noted under the "Details" section instead of being hidden away in "Possible Issues". Note that the `Method` option's possible values are not documented, and the `PerformanceGoal` option is not mentioned either under "Details" or "Options". I just sent some feedback about this doc page, I think it can use some improvement.